# navigator.userAgent for non Smart devices

Tags: javascript, navigator, smart-device

It is simple to detect the smart device from navigator.userAgent

like navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) , navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i), etc.

How do i get know that a request came from a system ( non smart device ) like from desktop, laptop,etc. using navigator.userAgent.

Answer (score 1):

You can test the `userAgent` value for the names of popular browsers! For example, the user agent string for the latest version of Firefox looks like this:

`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:6.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0.2`

Comment: I don't want to detect browser, I want to check either request came from smart device or some non smart device

Comment: Detecting the browser can tell you if the user is using a browser on a PC or a smart device. If you don't want to look for the browser string, why not simply invert your check for a smart device? If the user agent says it's not any of the smart devices, then it must be another device - mostly likely a computer!

Answer (score 1):

[Browser detection is bad](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2006/08/the_dangers_of.html). It's always better to opt for [feature detection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Browser_Feature_Detection) instead.